# Let $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ be two different curves. $\alpha'(t)=T(t)-k(t)T(t)\lambda(t)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, proof-explanation, frenet-frame

I can't understand a step in a solution:

> Let $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ be two different curves. Suppose that $\beta(t)=\alpha(t)+\lambda(t)N(t)$.
>
> Then:
>
> $$\beta'(t)=\alpha'(t)+\lambda'(t)N(t)+\lambda(t)N'(t)=T(t)-k(t)T(t)\lambda(t)+\lambda'(t)N(t)-\lambda(t)\tau(t)B(t).$$

How they arrive to $\alpha'(t)=T(t)-k(t)T(t)\lambda(t)$? I suppose that they are writing $T_{\alpha(t)}(t)$ in $\beta(t)$ frame, or something similar, right?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think $ \alpha' $ is just $ T(t) $. The other term $ -k(t) T(t) \lambda(t) $ comes from $ \lambda(t) N'(t) $, using the Frenet equations for $ N'(t) $. (Although I am confused by the sign.)

Comment: @user81327 $\lambda(t)N'(t)$ appears behind these terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a direct application of arc rate. See *Frenet -Serret* relations, for arc rate of normal. Adopt the same $TNB$ vector handedness of forming a right or a left handed system.(RH parallel Bertrand above LH parallel below).

Comment: You're right, I didn't see it...

Thanks!